# customizable buttons, It is correct or is there a better option?

Tags: android, int, android-tv, smart-tv

I want to customize the buttons, in place to appear "title0, TITLE1", etc.  I want to put something of my own, LocalVideo, listvideo .. etc.
The only solution I found it so. but I do not think that is correct.
Must be something different for sure.

code stock:

```
                /* CardPresenter */
    HeaderItem cardPresenterHeader = new HeaderItem(1, "CardPresenter");
    CardPresenter cardPresenter = new CardPresenter();
    ArrayObjectAdapter cardRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(cardPresenter);

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        if(i%3 == 0) {
            movie.setCardImageUrl("http://heimkehrend.raindrop.jp/kl-hacker/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/DSC02580.jpg");
        } else if (i%3 == 1) {
            movie.setCardImageUrl("http://heimkehrend.raindrop.jp/kl-hacker/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/DSC02630.jpg");
        } else {
            movie.setCardImageUrl("http://heimkehrend.raindrop.jp/kl-hacker/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/DSC02529.jpg");
        }
        movie.setTitle("title" + i);
        movie.setStudio("studio" + i);
        cardRowAdapter.add(movie);
    }

    mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(cardPresenterHeader, cardRowAdapter));
```

code changed:

```
                /* CardPresenter */
    HeaderItem cardPresenterHeader = new HeaderItem(1, "CardPresenter");
    CardPresenter cardPresenter = new CardPresenter();
    ArrayObjectAdapter cardRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(cardPresenter);

 for(int i=0; i<1; i++) {
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        if(i%3 == 0) {
            movie.setCardImageUrl("http://heimkehrend.raindrop.jp/kl-hacker/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/DSC02580.jpg");
        }
        movie.setTitle("Videoview");
        movie.setStudio("Video local video");
        cardRowAdapter.add(movie);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<1; i++) {
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        if(i%3 == 0) {
            movie.setCardImageUrl("http://heimkehrend.raindrop.jp/kl-hacker/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/DSC02580.jpg");
        }
        movie.setTitle("Listview");
        movie.setStudio("Listview local video");
        cardRowAdapter.add(movie);
    }
    mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(cardPresenterHeader, cardRowAdapter));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring [this site](http://corochann.com/android-tv-application-hands-on-tutorial-3-105.html), please ask me.

Is this what you want?

```
    /* CardPresenter */
    HeaderItem cardPresenterHeader = new HeaderItem(1, "CardPresenter");
    CardPresenter cardPresenter = new CardPresenter();
    ArrayObjectAdapter cardRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(cardPresenter);

    // Create movie1 object
    Movie movie1 = new Movie();
    movie1.setCardImageUrl("http://heimkehrend.raindrop.jp/kl-hacker/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/DSC02580.jpg");
    movie1.setTitle("Videoview");
    movie1.setStudio("Video local video");

    // Create movie2 object
    Movie movie2 = new Movie();
    movie2.setCardImageUrl("http://heimkehrend.raindrop.jp/kl-hacker/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/DSC02580.jpg");
    movie2.setTitle("Listview");
    movie2.setStudio("Listview local video");

    // put movie1 and movie2 into cardRowAdapter
    cardRowAdapter.add(movie1);
    cardRowAdapter.add(movie2);

    // show cardRowAdapter in listrow
    mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(cardPresenterHeader, cardRowAdapter));
```